# 1 screen extended to 3 on a notebook with ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4670 - how?

Tags: display, adapter, vga, hdmi

Not sure if a proper stackexchange forum, but couldn't find any more related.

Is graphic card ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4670 able to handle 2 screens?
If it does, what Multi-Display Adapters you reccommend?

Comment: Did you miss SuperUser.com?

Answer (score 0):

The electrical design of all graphic ports is pretty smart at detecting the 75 Ohm termination impedance of monitor signals.  Once this is detected on boot , the external VGA is cloned until the desktop configuration is loaded. Initially it will be blank or disabled until you chose a (.) beside extend this monitor [2].  You can expect [2] but  using the HDMI port in addition to get [3] may have restrictions to the overall desktop size of shared CPU/GPU memory space.

If you disconnect the cable, the video adapter will sense the disconnect of 75 Ohms and then react by disabling the video signal and pushing all the icons and windows to the main screen.  Isn't Ohm's Law wonderful?

Comment: No, they actually detect the display by querying it over the Display Data Channel.  But what does this have to do with the original question?